# Count concurent HttpClient requests with RxJS infinitelly

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm stuck on trying to calculate concurrent HttpClient requests in a nice reactive way. I this example I use intervals as requests triggers but in reality the would be some other asynchronous events. I DIDN'T WANT to tap and update some global `counter` observable before and after each `httpClient` call. I'm pretty sure that there should be some nicer way.

```
let a11$ = interval(1000); 
let a12$ = interval(1500);
let a13$ = interval(3000);

let c1$ = combineLatest(a11$, a12$, a13$).pipe(
    map(([a, b ,c]) => {
        return this.httpClient.get(`http://example.com/${a}${b}${c}`);
    })
)

let a21$ = interval(4000); 
let a22$ = interval(4500);
let a23$ = interval(5000);


let c2$ = combineLatest(a21$, a22$, a23$).pipe(
    map(([a, b ,c]) => {
        return this.httpClient.get(`http://example.com/${a}${b}${c}`);
    })
)


let count$ = null; // I want to calculate how many concurrent HTTP requests produced by c1$ and c2$ are being executed at the moment. Infinitely.
```

Comment: So you want to update `count$` (emit `next` notification) every time a new request has started or completed?

Comment: @martin yes, I do.

Comment: You'll still have to be using `tap()` even though you can wrap `counter` variable into a local scope so it won't be global.

Answer (score 0):

there is a `count()` operator with rxjs and you can split them into two stream

```
const combined=combineLatest(a21$, a22$, a23$)

const count=combined.pipe(count())

const c2$=combined.pipe(
    map(([a, b ,c]) => {
        return this.httpClient.get(`http://example.com/${a}${b}${c}`);
    })
)
// get the counts
count.subscribe(console.log)
```